# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can testers benefit from knowing the status of unit tests?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9490/can-testers-benefit-from-knowing-the-status-of-unit-tests)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Fitnesse vs Robot](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9336/fitnesse-vs-robot)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Disabling failing tests in CI if they discover known bugs](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9401/disabling-failing-tests-in-ci-if-they-discover-known-bugs)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are some Invalid data inputs that will break a text box?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9441/what-are-some-invalid-data-inputs-that-will-break-a-text-box)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Page Object Design: Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby gems "site_prism" or "page_object"?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9345/page-object-design-is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-ruby-gems-site-prism-or-p)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Trying to simulate users logging in but staying idle](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/trying-to-simulate-users-logging-in-but-staying-idle)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [JMeter: how to specify header for page request but not for embedded resource requests?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9484/jmeter-how-to-specify-header-for-page-request-but-not-for-embedded-resource-req)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [QA tool with feature for automatic recording of user actions](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9360/qa-tool-with-feature-for-automatic-recording-of-user-actions)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Obfuscating logs before publishing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/obfuscating-logs-before-publishing)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Robot framework installation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/robot-framework-installation)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed [question 9320](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/obfuscating-logs-before-publishing), and the question and answer both look pretty good - but I reviewed it as *Needs Improvement* because unless I search for the exact wording of the question title, it's not showing up in a google search.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across [What are some Invalid data inputs that will break a text box?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9441/what-are-some-invalid-data-inputs-that-will-break-a-text-box) and am debating whether it's close enough in content to [What are the possible test scenario's to test a Text field?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8067/what-are-the-possible-test-scenarios-to-test-a-text-field) - which I ironically found trying to search for the first one... In any event, I'm going with NI. I'd like to get a little input because obviously if I close it, it's insta-closed, there's no community input on it.